# The comma operator in a function argument

Tags: c, arguments, expression, comma-operator

I was reading this excerpt from the GNU C manual:

> You use the comma operator, to separate two (ostensibly related) expressions.

Later in the description:

> If you want to use the comma operator in a function argument, you need
>   to put parentheses around it.  That’s because commas in a function
>   argument list have a different meaning: they separate arguments.

Until now, everything is alright. The weird part is:

> `foo (x,  (y=47,  x),  z);` is a function call with just three
>   arguments.  (The second argument is `(y=47, x)` .)

The question is: how is the parameter pushed on the stack, how do I access it from within the function?

Comment: The function receives the arguments (x, x, z). Where is the problem?

Comment: Parameters don't have to be pushed on the stack. Stack may not even exist

Comment: The problem as I understand it is that OP is imagining that the whole parenthesized construct is "pushed" into the stack/ passed as a parameter. Missing the point that it is *evaluated* first.

Comment: a) this is not a GNU extension, but standard C behaviour, b) there indeed need not be a stack, and in x86-64, the arguments are not even pushed on stack, the arguments are as Sourav told...

Comment: Each of the three arguments is evaluated, and the results are passed to the function.  Remember, C is call by value, not call by name (you're thinking it behaves the way it would in Algol).

Comment: The C language does not have a stack. This is also not way related to functions, but normal expressions. It is not clear what you problem is apart from understanding how the comma-operator works. This is explained in every C book.

Comment: @TomKarzes Can you please elaborate more on the part where you said : "C is a call by value, not call by name". What does it mean ?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, i understand my mistake when i assumed that parameters are pushed onto the stack (I know that X86-64 now uses many registers before pushing things onto the stack & there may exist architectures where there's no stack). But i asked the question like that because i have a desire to understand what could happen under the hood (even if it is implementation dependent).

Comment: There are several different argument passing styles in programming languages.  "Call by value" means the arguments are evaluated as expressions, and the results are passed to the called function.  Call by reference means references to the arguments are passed to the call function, which may then modify the arguments in the caller.  Call by name means the arguments are dynamically evaluated in the context of the caller.  Algol was famous for using it.  It's the most obscure and confusing of the threee styles I mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case,

```
  foo (x, (y=47, x), z);
```

is functionally similar as

```
  foo (x, x, z);
```

As per the property of comma operator, the LHS operand is evaluated and the result is discarded, then the RHS operand is evaluated and that's the result.

For sake of completion, quoting the `C11`, chapter §6.5.17

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

Point to note: the variable `y` will be updated, as the LHS operand is evaluated as a void expression, but has no effect on *this funcion call*. In case, the `y` is a global variable and used in `foo()` function, it will see an initial value of `47`.

That said, to answer

> *how is the parameter pushed on the stack*

is very very implementation (architecture) dependent. C does not specify any order for function argument passing and some architecture may event not use "stack" for function argument passing, at all!!

Comment: with the side effect of setting y to 47, which could be at global scope.

Comment: @Bathsheba obviously sir, but that does not have any impact on the function _call_ in _this_ case.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "functionally similar" therefore.

Comment: @Bathsheba OK, I elaborated my answer. Any alternate wordings which can avoid any miscommunication? Please feel free to edit. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Gracious!!

Comment: Perhaps it would help the OP to observe that C function calls have *pass-by-value* semantics.  That is implied by this fine answer, but not explicitly stated.  Thus, from the perspective of the details of the function call, the second function argument is *not* the expression `(y=47, x)`; rather, it is the value that results from evaluating that expression.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know that C evaluates expressions then pass results as parameters. But it was kind of weird for this situation with a comma operator. Now it is clear that the left operand is evaluated and then discarded. That makes sense now, since it is the second parameter which gets evaluated and its result is passed as a parameter value.

Comment: What's the motivation behind the downtick?